# HttpPost action method recalled when the view presented by it is reloaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel, actionmethod

I have an HTTPPOST action method that receives a model and saves it to the database:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddDocument(Document doc){
   DocumentRepository repo= GetDocumentRepository();
   repo.SaveDocument(doc);
   return View(viewName: "DocViewer", model: doc);
}
```

So this method receives the model, saves it and then returns it to the `DocViewer` view to display the added document. I have two problems including the one in the question

1. If I press F5 after the `DocViewer` is presented I get a warning that the post method will be invoked again. How do I avoid this? I'm sure there's a general practice
2. In the `DocViewer` view I have defined HTML elements like this:

> ```
> <div>Full name</div>
> <div>@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.FullName)</div> 
> <div>Address</div>
> <div>@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Address)</div> //and so on
> ```

But what I get is the following output:

```
Full name FullName
Address Address
```

Shouldn't I get the actual value but not the property name (or the Display Name if it's provided)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Post action do not return model object back to view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddDocument(Document doc)
{
   DocumentRepository repo= GetDocumentRepository();
   repo.SaveDocument(doc);
   //return View("DocViewer");
   TempData["Document"] = doc;
   return RedirectToAction("DocViewer","ControllerName");
}
```

and in **DocViewer** action:

```
public ActionResult DocViewer()
{
   Document doc = TempData["DocViewer"] as Document;
   return View(doc);

}
```

**UPDATED:**

you have to redirect to **DocViewer** view via its action to avoid form post again if **F5** pressed.

See [**details here**](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/06/22/cleaning-up-posts-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: the instead of returning view redirect to view via action of it

Comment: This really solves the first problem. How about the second one? Why don't I get the model property values instead of their names?

Comment: It's all set up now, @Ehsan. I've found the reason. Take a look at my answer if you care.

Comment: what was the 2nd problem i did'nt understood @MikeJM

Comment: When using @Html.LabelFor I wasn't getting the values of the model properties, I was getting the property names. So for example, for the property FullName I wasn't getting Joe Black, I was getting FullName.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem was indeed solved by Ehsan's answer. I shouldn't be returning a model object to the view, instead I should redirect to another action method.
 The second problem arose because of the nature of `LabelFor` helper method. The thing is `LabelFor` just creates labels, which is meant to label values. To show the actual value not using text-box there's another method called `DisplayTextFor`. After using that method I could get the actual value.